# Non-Constant Partitioning of a List with Order Analysis

Tags: partitions

Let's say I have a set of numbers "r" whose sum equals 15, and I want to randomize all values up to and including that sum from and including 1 into a set called "a". So far I have this:

```
r = {4,5,6}
ord = Range[15]
a = RandomSample[ord]
```

And though for everyone the evaluation would yield a randomly different answer each time, for me the answer was:

```
{4,5,6}
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}
{13,2,8,15,7,12,14,3,11,1,6,5,9,4,10}
```

Now, half of the challenge I'm stuck on is how to Partition "a" (the last line of the output above) in the consecutive amounts of the set "r" ({4,5,6}), such that the output next would look like:

```
{{13,2,8,15},{7,12,4,3,11},{1,6,5,9,4,10}} // Lengths 4,5,6 respectively
```

Lastly I want the Ordering function applied to each of these subsets in one fell stroke, so that the final output derived from the above line would be:

```
{{2,3,1,4},{4,3,1,5,2},{1,5,3,2,4,6}}
```

Of course the answer would look different depending on what random sample was generated, but I need the logic to be consistent with what's here outlined.

Thanks!

Comment: ``b=Internal`PartitionRagged[a, r]`` and `Ordering/@b`?

Comment: @kglr That is exactly right, thanks so much! Very elegant : ]

Comment: @kglr this is great! what is "Internal`PartitionRagged" I can't find any documentation

Comment: @Jenny, it is an undocumented function. Try ``Information[Internal`PartitionRagged]`` for a description of what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
r = {4, 5, 6};
ord = Range[15];
a = RandomSample[ord]
```

> {14, 2, 5, 1, 8, 12, 10, 13, 15, 11, 9, 4, 7, 6, 3}

```
b = Internal`PartitionRagged[a, r]
```

or, if you have version 10 or a newer version

```
b = FoldPairList[TakeDrop,a,r]
```

both give

> {{14, 2, 5, 1}, {8, 12, 10, 13, 15}, {11, 9, 4, 7, 6, 3}}

And

```
Ordering /@ b
```

> {{4, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 5}, {6, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1}}